# Lost remote connectio after working several months

Tags: 22.04, remote-desktop, vnc, remote-access, remote-login

Setup:
At Workplace:

1. Ubuntu desktop computer
2. I was able to connect to the above ubuntu computer from my laptop using VNC.

At home:

1. I would login to my virtual work network and I would connect through My laptop using same VNC.

What usually I do: on my windows laptop, open the VNC, click the ubuntu_computer_icon and bingo. That's it. I would connect to it. This ran good for a few months in a row.

Now: Its gone. I cannot connect to the ubuntu computer. I get lost connection error. I tried `SSH`, even that is not working.

Did I do recently something on the Ubuntu: Well, one thing I did was, scheduled a auto-reboot in the night time. So, suppose, if I loose connection when I am far away, this reboot will ensure me that I can reconnect to it after the reboot. So, I don't have to come physically to the computer, perform reboot.

I need your help on how to enable remote RDP  on ubuntu, so, this won't raise error even during scheduled reboot of the computer.

Comment: There are too many unknowns in your question. Is your Ubuntu desktop at home, at work on in the cloud? Does it have a public static IP address? Does it have a static private IP address in it is at home behind a router? Can you remote connect to your Ubuntu computer when you are connected to the same home or work network using the static private IP address? Can you connect to your Ubuntu computer using another protocol such as `ssh`? Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1478622/edit) and answer all these and other questions we ask in the comments.

Comment: @user68186 I updated my question. Sorry for the late reply.